# Accessing multiple outputs in a function, combined with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a function like this:

```
computeLagError <- function(x, y)
{
    until = length(x)

    msd.t <- rep(0,until)
    sd.t  <- rep(0,until)

    for (dt in 1:until)
    {
        displacement.x <- as.vector(na.omit(x[(1+dt):length(x)]) - x[1:(length(x)-dt)])
        displacement.y <- as.vector(na.omit(y[(1+dt):length(y)]) - y[1:(length(y)-dt)])
        sqrdispl <- (displacement.x^2 + displacement.y^2)
        msd.t[dt] <- mean(sqrdispl)
        sd.t[dt] <- sd(msd.t) # The error increases for every point, as time lag has fewer points
    }
    data_table <- as.data.table(msd.t, sd.t, sqrdispl)

    return(data_table)
}
```

And I'd like to return the three values `msd.t`, `sd.t` and `sqrdispl` for use with dplyr.

```
df <- df %>% group_by(track_id) %>% mutate(msd = computeLagError(x, y)[,1],
                                           lag = seq_along(msd),
                                           stepsize = computeLagError(x, y)[,2],
                                           lag_error = computeLagError(x,y)[,3])
```

But I get errors saying that subsetting doesn't work on a function. If I instead try to return the values as a list, I can somehow only access the first element in each list.

My solution thus far has been to have 3 separate function returning 3 different values, but this seems quite hacky. The above even calls my function 3 times, whereas I'd like to call it once and access the values.

Comment: It looks somewhat inefficient to run the function 3 times. Have you considered using `dplyr::do` (or `purrr`) instead of mutate?

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors in your function. e.g., you return the package data.table instead of the defined datatable. Also the binding of vectors is not working. Check this:

```
computeLagError <- function(x, y)
{
    until = length(x)

    msd.t <- rep(0,until)
    sd.t  <- rep(0,until)

    for (dt in 1:until)
    {
        displacement.x <- as.vector(na.omit(x[(1+dt):length(x)]) - x[1:(length(x)-dt)])
        displacement.y <- as.vector(na.omit(y[(1+dt):length(y)]) - y[1:(length(y)-dt)])
        sqrdispl <- (displacement.x^2 + displacement.y^2)
        msd.t[dt] <- mean(sqrdispl)
        sd.t[dt] <- sd(msd.t) # The error increases for every point, as time lag has fewer points
    }
    data_table <- cbind.data.frame(msd.t, sd.t, sqrdispl)

    return(data_table)
}
```

Some example data:

```
df = data.frame(track_id=as.factor(rep(c(1,2),each=50)),x=c(1:100),y=c(1:100))
```

Your code:

```
df <- df %>% group_by(track_id) %>% mutate(msd = computeLagError(x, y)[,1],
                                           lag = seq_along(msd),
                                           stepsize = computeLagError(x, y)[,2],
                                           lag_error = computeLagError(x,y)[,3])
```

Comment: Whoops. I have no idea how the period snuck in. It's only Monday morning here. Updating main post as this is an eye-searing error.

Comment: Anyway, thanks. It works. But this will call the same function 3 times, accessing separate columns each time, right?

Comment: Same here :) Yes it does.. hmm the easiest is to assign to an object and select columns accordingly but I'm not sure whether this is possible in dplyr. I ll have a look